# how to use if statement with multiple variable?

Tags: php, if-statement

this is what i already tried.

```
<?php
$a=4;
$b=6;
if ($a>=$b) {$x="xx";}
elseif ($b-$a=1) {$x="yy";}
elseif ($b-$a=2) {$x="zz";}
echo "$x"; ?>
```

so, i have written my code like this. but it give me the wrong answer. how to make the code get to this statement below?
and the problem is how to make the code get to the statement below? which 1 to fix?

```
elseif ($b-$a=2) {$x="zz";}
echo"$x";
```

because when i run it on my browser it gave me

```
$x="yy";
```

instead of 
    $x="zz";

and why so hard to makes question at this website?

Comment: One `=` is an assignment, two is comparison.

Comment: Seeing `=` inside an `if` statement should make your eye twitch. If not, you'll need to develop a sense for that kind of trouble because this sort of thing stings even seasoned programmers all the time.

Comment: You could benefit from a few good PHP tutorials.

Comment: so what do i with it?

Comment: Check https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_operator_types.htm for all valid operators, you need to use a **comparison operator** but you are instead using an assignment operator

Comment: thanks, i added the = and its done.

Comment: _and why so hard to makes question at this website?_ What???